# Set up public facing reverse proxy for a specific server

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, varnish

At my work place, we have run out of available IP addresses to assign to our public facing UAT server. Because of this, we route all traffic to port 80 on our UAT server from port 9999 on another servers IP address. This works fine in most cases but testing external services such as PayPal becomes impossible as PayPal removes port numbers from callback urls so our public facing UAT server can never interact with payment gateways.

As a workaround, I suggested the following:

Purchase the cheapest Digital Ocean container with a unique IP address.

Point all UAT domain dns's to this container.

Block all traffic except the container from the UAT server.

Set up some kind of reverse proxy to route all traffic from the DO container to the UAT server.

The part I do not know how to do is the reverse proxy part. I assume I would need Nginx or Varnish. However, this solution needs to handle user sessions and file uploads too with the DO container acting ONLY as a proxy and not storing this information.

Is this possible? If so, how would I go about it? I have no preference for the OS or software for the DO container so any suggestions are welcome.

Please don't tell me how we should just get another IP address instead of going for this long winded solution. I am well aware that this is overkill, however currently we cannot purchase any other IP blocks so this is a temporary measure until that happens.

Answer (score 0):

Reverse proxy is a fine solution here. This way you can have dozens of servers on one public IP.

I know nothing about Digital Ocean and your hosting environment, so I can only recommend placing proxy as close to the application server as possible, to avoid double latencies.

Reverse proxies work well in most configuration, although often require special configuration in the application. To avoid problems, it is helpful to map identically-named URIs on app server and proxy (http://proxy.host/uri to http://app.host/uri and likes).  Apache httpd offers a reliable proxy solution, check manual for `ProxyPass`, `ProxyPassReverse`, `ProxyPreserveHost`.